# flask rest videos treaming

Tags: c#, rest, azure, flask

I am trying to build a live video streaming service where I run a python flask server on Azure, and have one client PUT frames on the server continuously, and another client GET the frames from the server. It works fine with low byte[] sizes but if I send bytes[] that are 1 MB or higher the process becomes very slow (1 fps). Is there any way to optimize the performance (delta compression, Huffman encoding etc)?